# SELECT COUNT(*) GROUP BY out zero rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Tables in my db:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  status smallint
);

CREATE TABLE phones (
  phone character varying,
  users integer[]
);
```

My Query for find phone numbers where status = 1:

```
SELECT phones.phone, COUNT(*) AS "count" 
FROM phones,items 
WHERE phones.phone = ANY (Array['7924445544', '8985545444'])
AND   items.user_id = ALL (phones.users) AND items.status = 1
GROUP BY phones.phone;
```

Query out:

```
   phone    | count
------------+------
 7924445588 |     3
```

Need out with ZERO count:

```
   phone    | count 
------------+-------
 8985545444 |     0
 7924445544 |     3
```

How to get that?

Comment: So now you mean all numbers asked for do exist?

Comment: Yes. But because of the GROUP BY "0" is not displayed

Comment: what do you mean by "because of the GROUP BY "0" is not displayed". Doesn't this imply 8985545444 was not selected per query constraints.

Comment: Why would you have an array of integer for `phones.users` - and not a plain `integer` FK column `phone.user_id`? That would make the query much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to create non-existing rows. (There are billions of them, at least...)
Do a `UNION ALL` with a select providing the result you want if that phone no doesn't exist.

```
<current query>
UNION ALL
select '8985545444',0
from one_row_table where not exists (select 1 from phones
                                     where phones.phone = '8985545444')
```

**EDIT:**
If the phone numbers do exists, but not fulfill the `WHERE` clause conditions, use a correlated sub-select to do the count:

```
SELECT phones.phone,
       (select count(*) from items
        where items.status = 1
          and items.user_id = phones.users) as "Count"
FROM phones
WHERE phones.phone = ANY (Array['7924445544', '8985545444'])
```

Comment: It works, thanks!: SELECT phones.phone,
       (select count(*) from items where items.status = 1 and items.user_id = ANY(phones.users)) as "Count"
FROM phones
WHERE phones.phone = ANY(Array['7924445588', '7890546789', '8985545444']);

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that in the query. However it is rather easy to do it if you want to:

```
WITH phone_seek AS(
   SELECT '8985545444' AS phone
   UNION ALL
   SELECT '7924445588 '
)
SELECT  phone_seek.phone, COUNT(items.id) AS "count"
FROM 
  phones_seek
  JOIN phones
    ON phones_seek.phone = phones.phones
  CROSS JOIN items
WHERE 
  items.user_id = ALL (phones.users) AND items.status = 1 
GROUP BY phones.phone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Count is an aggregate function and generally db engines produces count 0 when no row matches the criteria.

The reason why your query produces no results is inclusion of your  phones.phone field in db and the group by.

1)    A cheap solution to this is select only count(*) as your application 
    already be knowing the phone number:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM phones, items
WHERE phones.phone = '8985545444'
  AND items.user_id = ALL (phones.users) AND items.status = 1 ;
```

2)    An ideal solution to this would be your application to handle 0 result 
    returned by db.

3)    And if you need db to do all job you may use something like:

```
SELECT  phones.phone, COUNT(*) AS "count"
FROM phones, items
WHERE phones.phone = '8985545444'
  AND items.user_id = ALL (phones.users) AND items.status = 1 
GROUP BY phones.phone;
UNION ALL
select '8985545444',0
from one_row_table where not exists (select 1 from phones
                                     where phones.phone = '8985545444')
```

Comment: Thanks... seems this solution was only known to you :P

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well versed with PostreSQL's array syntax, but this seems to be a simple outer join:

```
SELECT phones.phone, COUNT(items.user_id) AS "count" 
FROM phones LEFT JOIN items 
  ON items.user_id = ALL (phones.users) 
 AND items.status = 1
WHERE phones.phone = ANY (Array['7924445544', '8985545444']) 
GROUP BY phones.phone;
```